# unable to find netplan directory in Debian 10

Tags: debian, networking, netplan

I am trying to configure the networking using Netplan in Debian 10. I have installed the Netplan package with the following commands.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install netplan --edge --classic
```

I have Netplan successfully installed.

```
root@debian:/home/karim# snap install netplan --edge --classic
snap "netplan" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
```

However, I am unable to find Netplan directory for configuration in etc or anywhere in my Debian 10.

```
root@debian:/home/karim# find . -name netplan
root@debian:/home/karim# whereis netplan
netplan:
root@debian:/home/karim#
```

Comment: In your second screenshot (please refrain from posting screenshots of terminal windows), your search is only encompassing the `/home/karim` directory. Since you installed the snap version of netplan, try this: `find /snap -name netplan`.

Comment: Or you could have installed the native debian package [netplan.io](https://packages.debian.org/buster/netplan.io) instead (which is named such to avoid a conflict with the older existing and unrelated package [netplan](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/netplan) to manage a calendar )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for it in `/root`. It is actually located at `/snap/netplan` with the executable located at `/snap/bin/netplan` which is actually a symlink to `/usr/bin/snap`.

You can find it with:

```
locate netplan

find / -name netplan
```

The configuration file is here:

```
/snap/core/7917/etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml
```

To edit the configuration file, go into `/root` and type this command to see where it is mounted:

```
mount | grep netplan
```

You'll receive output like this showing that it's a squash filesystem mounted as read-only.

```
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_7917.snap on /snap/core/7917 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
```

Unmount and unsquash it (you may not nead the `-l -f` for `umount`):

```
umount -l -f /snap/core/7917

unsquashfs /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_7917.snap
```

You will see a directory in `/root` called `squashfs-root`. You can edit the config file inside with any text editor and convert it back to `squashfs`:

```
vim squashfs-root/etc/netplan/00-snapd-config.yaml

mksquashfs squashfs-root core_7917.snap
```

Copy it back to where it was and remount it:

```
cp -f core_7917.snap /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_7917.snap

mount -t squashfs -o ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_7917.snap /snap/core/7917
```

The modified config file is now back where it was.

Comment: Thank you Nasir. I see a lot of files in the /snap directory. Which file do I need to edit for network configuration? 

As in Ubuntu 18, 01-network-manager-all.yaml is used which is located in /etc/netpaln.

Comment: @user3541877 I've added the config file to my answer.

Comment: but the file is unwriteable.

Comment: @user3541877 Are you doing it as root or a regular user?

Comment: I have tried with both users

Comment: @user3541877 Copy it to `/root` to edit it and then back to `/snap/core/7917/etc/netplan/` to apply it.

Comment: I am unable to copy it to ......./Netplan directory and also unable to create any new file or directory inside ....../Netplan.

It says "Read only file system"

Comment: @user3541877 Updated once again with instructions on how to modify the config file.